# Retirar caracteres especial e acentos em javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Pessoal estou tentando retirar caracteres especial em javascript.
Mais estou com um problema, está sendo excluído o caractere e não é isso que eu queria. Gostaria que só fosse retirado o carácter especial.

```js
  var texto =  "joão 1444?";
  var er = /[^a-z0-9]/gi;
  texto = texto.replace(er, "");
  console.log(texto);
```

Comment: Está sendo excluído o caractere e não é isso que eu queria. O que quiz dizer com essa parte? Repare que vc está sobrescrevendo a variável texto.

Comment: Gostaria só de excluir o caracte e numero, mais por exeplo eu escrevo joão e exclui a palavra ã e fica joo.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/406366/112052

Answer (score 5):

Pelo que entendi nos comentarios você quer remover os acentos  e os caracteres especiais. Tente remover primeiro os acentos para depois remover os caracteres especiais.

```js
str = 'joão?';
str = str.replace(/[ÀÁÂÃÄÅ]/g,"A");
str = str.replace(/[àáâãäå]/g,"a");
str = str.replace(/[ÈÉÊË]/g,"E");
console.log(str.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi,''));
```

Answer (score 4):

Para futuros visitantes desse tópico, recomendo ver a resposta para esse outro tópico
[Remover acentos (javascript)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/237762/remover-acentos-javascript)

A alternativa mais elegante, fácil e rápida foi essa:

```
string.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");
```

Answer (score 3):

infelizmente não existe uma expressão regular simples que trate os caracteres especiais, a sua melhor opção aqui é mapear os mesmos.

Em outra pergunta, eu já entrei no merito de como mapear os caracteres especiais:

[Regex string javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/114482/regex-string-javascript/114587#answer-114621)

```js
var charMap = {"0":"0","1":"1","2":"2","3":"3","4":"4","5":"5","6":"6","7":"7","8":"8","9":"9","A":"A","B":"B","C":"C","D":"D","E":"E","F":"F","G":"G","H":"H","I":"I","J":"J","K":"K","L":"L","M":"M","N":"N","O":"O","P":"P","Q":"Q","R":"R","S":"S","T":"T","U":"U","V":"V","W":"W","X":"X","Y":"Y","Z":"Z","a":"a","b":"b","c":"c","d":"d","e":"e","f":"f","g":"g","h":"h","i":"i","j":"j","k":"k","l":"l","m":"m","n":"n","o":"o","p":"p","q":"q","r":"r","s":"s","t":"t","u":"u","v":"v","w":"w","x":"x","y":"y","z":"z","ª":"a","²":"2","³":"3","¹":"1","º":"o","À":"A","Á":"A","Â":"A","Ã":"A","Ä":"A","Å":"A","Ç":"C","È":"E","É":"E","Ê":"E","Ë":"E","Ì":"I","Í":"I","Î":"I","Ï":"I","Ð":"D","Ñ":"N","Ò":"O","Ó":"O","Ô":"O","Õ":"O","Ö":"O","Ø":"O","Ù":"U","Ú":"U","Û":"U","Ü":"U","Ý":"Y","à":"a","á":"a","â":"a","ã":"a","ä":"a","å":"a","ç":"c","è":"e","é":"e","ê":"e","ë":"e","ì":"i","í":"i","î":"i","ï":"i","ð":"d","ñ":"n","ò":"o","ó":"o","ô":"o","õ":"o","ö":"o","ø":"o","ù":"u","ú":"u","û":"u","ü":"u","ý":"y","ÿ":"y","Ā":"A","ā":"a","Ă":"A","ă":"a","Ą":"A","ą":"a","Ć":"C","ć":"c","Ĉ":"C","ĉ":"c","Ċ":"C","ċ":"c","Č":"C","č":"c","Ď":"D","ď":"d","Đ":"D","đ":"d","Ē":"E","ē":"e","Ĕ":"E","ĕ":"e","Ė":"E","ė":"e","Ę":"E","ę":"e","Ě":"E","ě":"e","Ĝ":"G","ĝ":"g","Ğ":"G","ğ":"g","Ġ":"G","ġ":"g","Ģ":"G","ģ":"g","Ĥ":"H","ĥ":"h","Ħ":"H","ħ":"h","Ĩ":"I","ĩ":"i","Ī":"I","ī":"i","Ĭ":"I","ĭ":"i","Į":"I","į":"i","İ":"I","Ĵ":"J","ĵ":"j","Ķ":"K","ķ":"k","Ĺ":"L","ĺ":"l","Ļ":"L","ļ":"l","Ľ":"L","ľ":"l","Ŀ":"L","ŀ":"l","Ł":"L","ł":"l","Ń":"N","ń":"n","Ņ":"N","ņ":"n","Ň":"N","ň":"n","Ō":"O","ō":"o","Ŏ":"O","ŏ":"o","Ő":"O","ő":"o","Ŕ":"R","ŕ":"r","Ŗ":"R","ŗ":"r","Ř":"R","ř":"r","Ś":"S","ś":"s","Ŝ":"S","ŝ":"s","Ş":"S","ş":"s","Š":"S","š":"s","Ţ":"T","ţ":"t","Ť":"T","ť":"t","Ũ":"U","ũ":"u","Ū":"U","ū":"u","Ŭ":"U","ŭ":"u","Ů":"U","ů":"u","Ű":"U","ű":"u","Ų":"U","ų":"u","Ŵ":"W","ŵ":"w","Ŷ":"Y","ŷ":"y","Ÿ":"Y","Ź":"Z","ź":"z","Ż":"Z","ż":"z","Ž":"Z","ž":"z","ſ":"s","Ơ":"O","ơ":"o","Ư":"U","ư":"u","Ǎ":"A","ǎ":"a","Ǐ":"I","ǐ":"i","Ǒ":"O","ǒ":"o","Ǔ":"U","ǔ":"u","Ǖ":"U","ǖ":"u","Ǘ":"U","ǘ":"u","Ǚ":"U","ǚ":"u","Ǜ":"U","ǜ":"u","Ǟ":"A","ǟ":"a","Ǡ":"A","ǡ":"a","Ǧ":"G","ǧ":"g","Ǩ":"K","ǩ":"k","Ǫ":"O","ǫ":"o","Ǭ":"O","ǭ":"o","ǰ":"j","Ǵ":"G","ǵ":"g","Ǹ":"N","ǹ":"n","Ǻ":"A","ǻ":"a","Ǿ":"O","ǿ":"o","Ȁ":"A","ȁ":"a","Ȃ":"A","ȃ":"a","Ȅ":"E","ȅ":"e","Ȇ":"E","ȇ":"e","Ȉ":"I","ȉ":"i","Ȋ":"I","ȋ":"i","Ȍ":"O","ȍ":"o","Ȏ":"O","ȏ":"o","Ȑ":"R","ȑ":"r","Ȓ":"R","ȓ":"r","Ȕ":"U","ȕ":"u","Ȗ":"U","ȗ":"u","Ș":"S","ș":"s","Ț":"T","ț":"t","Ȟ":"H","ȟ":"h","Ȧ":"A","ȧ":"a","Ȩ":"E","ȩ":"e","Ȫ":"O","ȫ":"o","Ȭ":"O","ȭ":"o","Ȯ":"O","ȯ":"o","Ȱ":"O","ȱ":"o","Ȳ":"Y","ȳ":"y","ʰ":"h","ʲ":"j","ʳ":"r","ʷ":"w","ʸ":"y","ˡ":"l","ˢ":"s","ˣ":"x","ͣ":"a","ͤ":"e","ͥ":"i","ͦ":"o","ͧ":"u","ͨ":"c","ͩ":"d","ͪ":"h","ͫ":"m","ͬ":"r","ͭ":"t","ͮ":"v","ͯ":"x","٠":"0","١":"1","٢":"2","٣":"3","٤":"4","٥":"5","٦":"6","٧":"7","٨":"8","٩":"9","۰":"0","۱":"1","۲":"2","۳":"3","۴":"4","۵":"5","۶":"6","۷":"7","۸":"8","۹":"9","߀":"0","߁":"1","߂":"2","߃":"3","߄":"4","߅":"5","߆":"6","߇":"7","߈":"8","߉":"9","०":"0","१":"1","२":"2","३":"3","४":"4","५":"5","६":"6","७":"7","८":"8","९":"9","০":"0","১":"1","২":"2","৩":"3","৪":"4","৫":"5","৬":"6","৭":"7","৮":"8","৯":"9","੦":"0","੧":"1","੨":"2","੩":"3","੪":"4","੫":"5","੬":"6","੭":"7","੮":"8","੯":"9","૦":"0","૧":"1","૨":"2","૩":"3","૪":"4","૫":"5","૬":"6","૭":"7","૮":"8","૯":"9","୦":"0","୧":"1","୨":"2","୩":"3","୪":"4","୫":"5","୬":"6","୭":"7","୮":"8","୯":"9","௦":"0","௧":"1","௨":"2","௩":"3","௪":"4","௫":"5","௬":"6","௭":"7","௮":"8","௯":"9","౦":"0","౧":"1","౨":"2","౩":"3","౪":"4","౫":"5","౬":"6","౭":"7","౮":"8","౯":"9","౸":"0","౹":"1","౺":"2","౻":"3","౼":"1","౽":"2","౾":"3","೦":"0","೧":"1","೨":"2","೩":"3","೪":"4","೫":"5","೬":"6","೭":"7","೮":"8","೯":"9","൦":"0","൧":"1","൨":"2","൩":"3","൪":"4","൫":"5","൬":"6","൭":"7","൮":"8","൯":"9","๐":"0","๑":"1","๒":"2","๓":"3","๔":"4","๕":"5","๖":"6","๗":"7","๘":"8","๙":"9","໐":"0","໑":"1","໒":"2","໓":"3","໔":"4","໕":"5","໖":"6","໗":"7","໘":"8","໙":"9","༠":"0","༡":"1","༢":"2","༣":"3","༤":"4","༥":"5","༦":"6","༧":"7","༨":"8","༩":"9","༪":"1","༫":"2","༬":"3","༭":"4","༮":"5","༯":"6","༰":"7","༱":"8","༲":"9","༳":"0","၀":"0","၁":"1","၂":"2","၃":"3","၄":"4","၅":"5","၆":"6","၇":"7","၈":"8","၉":"9","႐":"0","႑":"1","႒":"2","႓":"3","႔":"4","႕":"5","႖":"6","႗":"7","႘":"8","႙":"9","፩":"1","፪":"2","፫":"3","፬":"4","፭":"5","፮":"6","፯":"7","፰":"8","፱":"9","០":"0","១":"1","២":"2","៣":"3","៤":"4","៥":"5","៦":"6","៧":"7","៨":"8","៩":"9","៰":"0","៱":"1","៲":"2","៳":"3","៴":"4","៵":"5","៶":"6","៷":"7","៸":"8","៹":"9","᠐":"0","᠑":"1","᠒":"2","᠓":"3","᠔":"4","᠕":"5","᠖":"6","᠗":"7","᠘":"8","᠙":"9","᥆":"0","᥇":"1","᥈":"2","᥉":"3","᥊":"4","᥋":"5","᥌":"6","᥍":"7","᥎":"8","᥏":"9","᧐":"0","᧑":"1","᧒":"2","᧓":"3","᧔":"4","᧕":"5","᧖":"6","᧗":"7","᧘":"8","᧙":"9","᧚":"1","᪀":"0","᪁":"1","᪂":"2","᪃":"3","᪄":"4","᪅":"5","᪆":"6","᪇":"7","᪈":"8","᪉":"9","᪐":"0","᪑":"1","᪒":"2","᪓":"3","᪔":"4","᪕":"5","᪖":"6","᪗":"7","᪘":"8","᪙":"9","᭐":"0","᭑":"1","᭒":"2","᭓":"3","᭔":"4","᭕":"5","᭖":"6","᭗":"7","᭘":"8","᭙":"9","᮰":"0","᮱":"1","᮲":"2","᮳":"3","᮴":"4","᮵":"5","᮶":"6","᮷":"7","᮸":"8","᮹":"9","᱀":"0","᱁":"1","᱂":"2","᱃":"3","᱄":"4","᱅":"5","᱆":"6","᱇":"7","᱈":"8","᱉":"9","᱐":"0","᱑":"1","᱒":"2","᱓":"3","᱔":"4","᱕":"5","᱖":"6","᱗":"7","᱘":"8","᱙":"9","ᴬ":"A","ᴮ":"B","ᴰ":"D","ᴱ":"E","ᴳ":"G","ᴴ":"H","ᴵ":"I","ᴶ":"J","ᴷ":"K","ᴸ":"L","ᴹ":"M","ᴺ":"N","ᴼ":"O","ᴾ":"P","ᴿ":"R","ᵀ":"T","ᵁ":"U","ᵂ":"W","ᵃ":"a","ᵇ":"b","ᵈ":"d","ᵉ":"e","ᵍ":"g","ᵏ":"k","ᵐ":"m","ᵒ":"o","ᵖ":"p","ᵗ":"t","ᵘ":"u","ᵛ":"v","ᵢ":"i","ᵣ":"r","ᵤ":"u","ᵥ":"v","ᵹ":"g","ᶜ":"c","ᶞ":"d","ᶠ":"f","ᶻ":"z","᷊":"r","ᷓ":"a","ᷗ":"c","ᷘ":"d","ᷙ":"d","ᷚ":"g","ᷜ":"k","ᷝ":"l","ᷠ":"n","ᷤ":"s","ᷥ":"s","ᷦ":"z","Ḁ":"A","ḁ":"a","Ḃ":"B","ḃ":"b","Ḅ":"B","ḅ":"b","Ḇ":"B","ḇ":"b","Ḉ":"C","ḉ":"c","Ḋ":"D","ḋ":"d","Ḍ":"D","ḍ":"d","Ḏ":"D","ḏ":"d","Ḑ":"D","ḑ":"d","Ḓ":"D","ḓ":"d","Ḕ":"E","ḕ":"e","Ḗ":"E","ḗ":"e","Ḙ":"E","ḙ":"e","Ḛ":"E","ḛ":"e","Ḝ":"E","ḝ":"e","Ḟ":"F","ḟ":"f","Ḡ":"G","ḡ":"g","Ḣ":"H","ḣ":"h","Ḥ":"H","ḥ":"h","Ḧ":"H","ḧ":"h","Ḩ":"H","ḩ":"h","Ḫ":"H","ḫ":"h","Ḭ":"I","ḭ":"i","Ḯ":"I","ḯ":"i","Ḱ":"K","ḱ":"k","Ḳ":"K","ḳ":"k","Ḵ":"K","ḵ":"k","Ḷ":"L","ḷ":"l","Ḹ":"L","ḹ":"l","Ḻ":"L","ḻ":"l","Ḽ":"L","ḽ":"l","Ḿ":"M","ḿ":"m","Ṁ":"M","ṁ":"m","Ṃ":"M","ṃ":"m","Ṅ":"N","ṅ":"n","Ṇ":"N","ṇ":"n","Ṉ":"N","ṉ":"n","Ṋ":"N","ṋ":"n","Ṍ":"O","ṍ":"o","Ṏ":"O","ṏ":"o","Ṑ":"O","ṑ":"o","Ṓ":"O","ṓ":"o","Ṕ":"P","ṕ":"p","Ṗ":"P","ṗ":"p","Ṙ":"R","ṙ":"r","Ṛ":"R","ṛ":"r","Ṝ":"R","ṝ":"r","Ṟ":"R","ṟ":"r","Ṡ":"S","ṡ":"s","Ṣ":"S","ṣ":"s","Ṥ":"S","ṥ":"s","Ṧ":"S","ṧ":"s","Ṩ":"S","ṩ":"s","Ṫ":"T","ṫ":"t","Ṭ":"T","ṭ":"t","Ṯ":"T","ṯ":"t","Ṱ":"T","ṱ":"t","Ṳ":"U","ṳ":"u","Ṵ":"U","ṵ":"u","Ṷ":"U","ṷ":"u","Ṹ":"U","ṹ":"u","Ṻ":"U","ṻ":"u","Ṽ":"V","ṽ":"v","Ṿ":"V","ṿ":"v","Ẁ":"W","ẁ":"w","Ẃ":"W","ẃ":"w","Ẅ":"W","ẅ":"w","Ẇ":"W","ẇ":"w","Ẉ":"W","ẉ":"w","Ẋ":"X","ẋ":"x","Ẍ":"X","ẍ":"x","Ẏ":"Y","ẏ":"y","Ẑ":"Z","ẑ":"z","Ẓ":"Z","ẓ":"z","Ẕ":"Z","ẕ":"z","ẖ":"h","ẗ":"t","ẘ":"w","ẙ":"y","ẛ":"s","Ạ":"A","ạ":"a","Ả":"A","ả":"a","Ấ":"A","ấ":"a","Ầ":"A","ầ":"a","Ẩ":"A","ẩ":"a","Ẫ":"A","ẫ":"a","Ậ":"A","ậ":"a","Ắ":"A","ắ":"a","Ằ":"A","ằ":"a","Ẳ":"A","ẳ":"a","Ẵ":"A","ẵ":"a","Ặ":"A","ặ":"a","Ẹ":"E","ẹ":"e","Ẻ":"E","ẻ":"e","Ẽ":"E","ẽ":"e","Ế":"E","ế":"e","Ề":"E","ề":"e","Ể":"E","ể":"e","Ễ":"E","ễ":"e","Ệ":"E","ệ":"e","Ỉ":"I","ỉ":"i","Ị":"I","ị":"i","Ọ":"O","ọ":"o","Ỏ":"O","ỏ":"o","Ố":"O","ố":"o","Ồ":"O","ồ":"o","Ổ":"O","ổ":"o","Ỗ":"O","ỗ":"o","Ộ":"O","ộ":"o","Ớ":"O","ớ":"o","Ờ":"O","ờ":"o","Ở":"O","ở":"o","Ỡ":"O","ỡ":"o","Ợ":"O","ợ":"o","Ụ":"U","ụ":"u","Ủ":"U","ủ":"u","Ứ":"U","ứ":"u","Ừ":"U","ừ":"u","Ử":"U","ử":"u","Ữ":"U","ữ":"u","Ự":"U","ự":"u","Ỳ":"Y","ỳ":"y","Ỵ":"Y","ỵ":"y","Ỷ":"Y","ỷ":"y","Ỹ":"Y","ỹ":"y","⁰":"0","ⁱ":"i","⁴":"4","⁵":"5","⁶":"6","⁷":"7","⁸":"8","⁹":"9","ⁿ":"n","₀":"0","₁":"1","₂":"2","₃":"3","₄":"4","₅":"5","₆":"6","₇":"7","₈":"8","₉":"9","ₐ":"a","ₑ":"e","ₒ":"o","ₓ":"x","ₕ":"h","ₖ":"k","ₗ":"l","ₘ":"m","ₙ":"n","ₚ":"p","ₛ":"s","ₜ":"t","ℂ":"C","ℊ":"g","ℋ":"H","ℌ":"H","ℍ":"H","ℎ":"h","ℏ":"h","ℐ":"I","ℑ":"I","ℒ":"L","ℓ":"l","ℕ":"N","ℙ":"P","ℚ":"Q","ℛ":"R","ℜ":"R","ℝ":"R","ℤ":"Z","ℨ":"Z","K":"K","Å":"A","ℬ":"B","ℭ":"C","ℯ":"e","ℰ":"E","ℱ":"F","ℳ":"M","ℴ":"o","ℹ":"i","ⅅ":"D","ⅆ":"d","ⅇ":"e","ⅈ":"i","ⅉ":"j","Ⅰ":"I","Ⅴ":"V","Ⅹ":"X","Ⅼ":"L","Ⅽ":"C","Ⅾ":"D","Ⅿ":"M","ⅰ":"i","ⅴ":"v","ⅹ":"x","ⅼ":"l","ⅽ":"c","ⅾ":"d","ⅿ":"m","ↅ":"6","①":"1","②":"2","③":"3","④":"4","⑤":"5","⑥":"6","⑦":"7","⑧":"8","⑨":"9","Ⓐ":"A","Ⓑ":"B","Ⓒ":"C","Ⓓ":"D","Ⓔ":"E","Ⓕ":"F","Ⓖ":"G","Ⓗ":"H","Ⓘ":"I","Ⓙ":"J","Ⓚ":"K","Ⓛ":"L","Ⓜ":"M","Ⓝ":"N","Ⓞ":"O","Ⓟ":"P","Ⓠ":"Q","Ⓡ":"R","Ⓢ":"S","Ⓣ":"T","Ⓤ":"U","Ⓥ":"V","Ⓦ":"W","Ⓧ":"X","Ⓨ":"Y","Ⓩ":"Z","ⓐ":"a","ⓑ":"b","ⓒ":"c","ⓓ":"d","ⓔ":"e","ⓕ":"f","ⓖ":"g","ⓗ":"h","ⓘ":"i","ⓙ":"j","ⓚ":"k","ⓛ":"l","ⓜ":"m","ⓝ":"n","ⓞ":"o","ⓟ":"p","ⓠ":"q","ⓡ":"r","ⓢ":"s","ⓣ":"t","ⓤ":"u","ⓥ":"v","ⓦ":"w","ⓧ":"x","ⓨ":"y","ⓩ":"z","⓪":"0","⓵":"1","⓶":"2","⓷":"3","⓸":"4","⓹":"5","⓺":"6","⓻":"7","⓼":"8","⓽":"9","⓿":"0","❶":"1","❷":"2","❸":"3","❹":"4","❺":"5","❻":"6","❼":"7","❽":"8","❾":"9","➀":"1","➁":"2","➂":"3","➃":"4","➄":"5","➅":"6","➆":"7","➇":"8","➈":"9","➊":"1","➋":"2","➌":"3","➍":"4","➎":"5","➏":"6","➐":"7","➑":"8","➒":"9","ⱼ":"j","ⱽ":"V","〇":"0","〡":"1","〢":"2","〣":"3","〤":"4","〥":"5","〦":"6","〧":"7","〨":"8","〩":"9","꘠":"0","꘡":"1","꘢":"2","꘣":"3","꘤":"4","꘥":"5","꘦":"6","꘧":"7","꘨":"8","꘩":"9","Ꝺ":"D","ꝺ":"d","Ꝼ":"F","ꝼ":"f","Ᵹ":"G","Ꞃ":"R","ꞃ":"r","Ꞅ":"S","ꞅ":"s","Ꞇ":"T","ꞇ":"t","Ꞡ":"G","ꞡ":"g","Ꞣ":"K","ꞣ":"k","Ꞥ":"N","ꞥ":"n","Ꞧ":"R","ꞧ":"r","Ꞩ":"S","ꞩ":"s","꣐":"0","꣑":"1","꣒":"2","꣓":"3","꣔":"4","꣕":"5","꣖":"6","꣗":"7","꣘":"8","꣙":"9","꤀":"0","꤁":"1","꤂":"2","꤃":"3","꤄":"4","꤅":"5","꤆":"6","꤇":"7","꤈":"8","꤉":"9","꧐":"0","꧑":"1","꧒":"2","꧓":"3","꧔":"4","꧕":"5","꧖":"6","꧗":"7","꧘":"8","꧙":"9","꩐":"0","꩑":"1","꩒":"2","꩓":"3","꩔":"4","꩕":"5","꩖":"6","꩗":"7","꩘":"8","꩙":"9","꯰":"0","꯱":"1","꯲":"2","꯳":"3","꯴":"4","꯵":"5","꯶":"6","꯷":"7","꯸":"8","꯹":"9","０":"0","１":"1","２":"2","３":"3","４":"4","５":"5","６":"6","７":"7","８":"8","９":"9","Ａ":"A","Ｂ":"B","Ｃ":"C","Ｄ":"D","Ｅ":"E","Ｆ":"F","Ｇ":"G","Ｈ":"H","Ｉ":"I","Ｊ":"J","Ｋ":"K","Ｌ":"L","Ｍ":"M","Ｎ":"N","Ｏ":"O","Ｐ":"P","Ｑ":"Q","Ｒ":"R","Ｓ":"S","Ｔ":"T","Ｕ":"U","Ｖ":"V","Ｗ":"W","Ｘ":"X","Ｙ":"Y","Ｚ":"Z","ａ":"a","ｂ":"b","ｃ":"c","ｄ":"d","ｅ":"e","ｆ":"f","ｇ":"g","ｈ":"h","ｉ":"i","ｊ":"j","ｋ":"k","ｌ":"l","ｍ":"m","ｎ":"n","ｏ":"o","ｐ":"p","ｑ":"q","ｒ":"r","ｓ":"s","ｔ":"t","ｕ":"u","ｖ":"v","ｗ":"w","ｘ":"x","ｙ":"y","ｚ":"z"} ;

var texto =  "joão 1444?";
var er = /\W/gi;
texto = texto.replace(er, function (match) {
  var base = charMap[match];
  return !base || er.test(base) ? "" : match;
});
console.log(texto);
```

Neste caso, será mantido todos os caracteres especiais.)

Answer (score 1):

Esse método remove os caracteres especiais, incluindo letras Maiúsculas e Minúsculas do seu código, após isso você apenas escolherá um evento para acionar essa função.

```js
especialCharMask (especialChar){
        especialChar = especialChar.replace('/[áàãâä]/ui', 'a');
        especialChar = especialChar.replace('/[éèêë]/ui', 'e');
        especialChar = especialChar.replace('/[íìîï]/ui', 'i');
        especialChar = especialChar.replace('/[óòõôö]/ui', 'o');
        especialChar = especialChar.replace('/[úùûü]/ui', 'u');
        especialChar = especialChar.replace('/[ç]/ui', 'c');
        especialChar = especialChar.replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', '_');
        especialChar = especialChar.replace('/_+/', '_'); //
        return especialChar;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Isso aqui funciona bem:

```js
   let string = "me formei, e agora José?"
    
   let resultado = string.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')
   
   console.log(resultado)
```

Encontrei nesse tópico aqui em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374822/remove-all-special-characters-with-regexp

Comment: `me formei e agora Jos`