# Função javascript texto para maiúsculo e remover acentos juntas

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte script funcionando perfeitamente, gostaria de implementar a função remover acentos já achei várias dicas mas não funcionaram, como não entendo de javascript, gostaria que se possível implementar a função em meu script já existente, obrigado, segue script:

```js
$(function(){
 $("#txtBusca").keyup(function(){
  var texto = $(this).val();
  
  $("#ulItens li").css("display", "block");
  $("#ulItens li").each(function(){
   // if($(this).text().indexOf(texto) < 0)
   //    $(this).css("display", "none");

   if($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(texto.toUpperCase()) < 0)
      $(this).css("display", "none");
      
  });
 });
});
```

```html
<div class="single">
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.20.2" />
     <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
     <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
 
    <!--Início Script de busca-->
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
 $("#txtBusca").keyup(function(){
  var texto = $(this).val();
  
  $("#ulItens li").css("display", "block");
  $("#ulItens li").each(function(){
   // if($(this).text().indexOf(texto) < 0)
   //    $(this).css("display", "none");

   if($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(texto.toUpperCase()) < 0)
      $(this).css("display", "none");
      
  });
 });
});
</script>      
 <!--Fim Script de busca-->

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Marcellus+SC'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.4/styles/solarized_dark.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://leituracrista.com/css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://leituracrista.com/css/custom.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://leituracrista.com/css/busca.css">
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS" href="http://leituracrista.com//index.xml">

    
    <title>Índice - O que Respondi - Mario Persona</title>
    
  </head>

  <body>

    <header >
      
      <div class="title"><a href="http://leituracrista.com/"  target="_parent">  Leitura Cristã</a></div>
    </header>

    <div class="container site">

 
  <div align="center" class="section">
    <header><div  align="center" class="title">ÍNDICE - O que respodi - Por Mario Persona</div></header></br>
    <div class="list-default"><nav id="TableOfContents">

<div class="busca">
    <!--<input id="filtro" type="text" placeholder="Busca Rápida">-->
    
       <input style="text-align: center;" type="text" id="txtBusca" placeholder="Busca Rápida..."/>

</div>

<ul id="ulItens" align="center">

<li><a href="http://leituracrista.com/o-que-respondi-volume-1/#o-que-preciso-fazer-para-ser-salvo">
  O que preciso fazer para ser salvo?
  </a></li>

<li><a href="http://leituracrista.com/o-que-respondi-volume-1/#o-que-significa-abba">
  O que significa Abba?
  </a></li>


<li><a href="http://leituracrista.com/o-que-respondi-volume-1/#por-que-há-tantas-denominações">
  Por que há tantas denominações?
  </a></li>

<li><a href="http://leituracrista.com/o-que-respondi-volume-1/#pode-explicar-espírito-alma-e-corpo">
  Pode explicar espírito, alma e corpo?
  </a></li>

<li><a href="http://leituracrista.com/o-que-respondi-volume-1/#quem-são-os-anjos-caídos">
  Quem são os anjos caídos?
  </a></li>

<li><a href="http://leituracrista.com/o-que-respondi-volume-1/#o-que-é-batismo-do-espírito-santo">
  O que é batismo do Espírito Santo?
  </a></li>

<li><a href="http://leituracrista.com/o-que-respondi-volume-1/#qual-é-o-pecado-sem-perdão">
  Qual é o pecado sem perdão?
  </a></li>

<li><a href="http://leituracrista.com/o-que-respondi-volume-1/#com-quem-se-casou-caim">
  Com quem se casou Caim?
  </a></li>

<li><a href="http://leituracrista.com/o-que-respondi-volume-1/#onde-celebrar-a-ceia-do-senhor">
  Onde celebrar a ceia do Senhor?
  </a></li>

<li><a href="http://leituracrista.com/o-que-respondi-volume-1/#há-diferença-entre-inferno-lago-de-fogo-hades-sheol-e-geena">
  Há diferença entre inferno, lago de fogo, hades, sheol e geena?
  </a></li>

<li><a href="http://leituracrista.com/o-que-respondi-volume-1/#o-cristão-deve-ir-à-guerra">
  O cristão deve ir à guerra?
  </a></li>

<li><a href="http://leituracrista.com/o-que-respondi-volume-1/#qual-o-significado-de-dois-dias-de-oséias-6-1-3">
  Qual o significado de dois dias de Oséias 6:1-3?
  </a></li>

<li><a href="http://leituracrista.com/o-que-respondi-volume-1/#o-que-significa-o-batismo">
  O que significa o Batismo?
  </a></li>

<li><a href="http://leituracrista.com/o-que-respondi-volume-1/#como-conviver-com-o-vazio-e-a-tristeza">
  Como conviver com o vazio e a tristeza?
  </a></li>

<li><a href="http://leituracrista.com/o-que-respondi-volume-1/#como-enfrentar-as-tentações">
  Como enfrentar as tentações?
  </a></li>


<li><a href="http://leituracrista.com/o-que-respondi-volume-1/#como-celebrar-a-ceia-do-senhor">
  Como celebrar a Ceia do Senhor?
  </a></li>

<li><a href="http://leituracrista.com/o-que-respondi-volume-1/#devo-divulgar-denominação">
  Devo divulgar denominação?
  </a></li>

<li><a href="http://leituracrista.com/o-que-respondi-volume-1/#a-bíblia-considera-a-mulher-inferior-ao-homem">
  A Bíblia considera a mulher inferior ao homem?
  </a></li>

<li><a href="http://leituracrista.com/o-que-respondi-volume-1/#existe-alguma-condição-para-falar-línguas-estranhas">
  Existe alguma condição para falar línguas estranhas?
  </a></li>

<li><a href="http://leituracrista.com/o-que-respondi-volume-1/#como-enfrentar-as-aflições">
  Como enfrentar as aflições?
  </a></li>

<li><a href="http://leituracrista.com/o-que-respondi-volume-1/#o-que-significa-a-mesa-do-senhor">
  O que significa a Mesa do Senhor?
  </a></li>

<li><a href="http://leituracrista.com/o-que-respondi-volume-1/#qual-religião-pode-me-salvar">
  Qual religião pode me salvar?
  </a></li>

<li><a href="http://leituracrista.com/o-que-respondi-volume-1/#em-que-templo-devo-adorar">
  Em que templo devo adorar?
  </a></li>

<li><a href="http://leituracrista.com/o-que-respondi-volume-1/#o-cristão-pode-beber-vinho">
  O cristão pode beber vinho?
  </a></li>
  
  </ul>
</nav></div>
  </div>
  

<script>
var links = document.links;
for (var i = 0, linksLength = links.length; i < linksLength; i++) {
    if (links[i].hostname != window.location.hostname) {
        links[i].target = 'right';
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Miguel, você quer apenas remover os acentos, ou substitui-los por seu respectivo carácter sem acento?

Comment: Pode usar como base: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124754/retirar-caracteres-especial-e-acentos-em-javascript

Comment: Pedro Camara Junior adicionei os códigos javascript e o html pra ficar melhor, não sei qual a opção funcionaria na busca se apenas remover ou substituir, desculpe minha ignorância não entendo de java, rsrs.

Comment: @MiguelSilva, nesse caso, acredito que o ideal é substituir pelos respectivos caracteres, não acha? Desse modo, você mantém o sentido da _string_ retornada.

Comment: @MiguelSilva você adicinou o código html que queria mas alterou o sentido da pergunta e ainda deixou a pergunta falando de java mas na realidade você quer perguntar sobre javascript. Consegue corrigi?

Comment: @FlávioGranato, corrigido

Comment: Miguel podes dar um exemplo de texto e como queres que fique?

Comment: @Sergio, eu coloquei o script e html acima, obrigado pela atenção

Comment: Miguel, o que eu queria era um exemplo de texto e como queres que fique.

Comment: @Segio Ah sim, desculpe, não tinha entendido a pergunta, rsrs
Vamos lá, meu problema é o seguinte:
tenho uma lista no seguinte formato:
<ul>
<li>É possível ver a Deus?</li>
<li>O que são denominações</li>
</ul>

Se o usuário digitar "deus" ou "Deus", em maiúsculo ou minúsculo vai encontrar a 1º linha sem problema (isto eu já consigo fazer)
Mas se ele digitar "denominações" vai encontrar a segunda linha sem problema, mas se digitar sem acento "denominacoes" não encontra, o que quero é que seja encontrado mesmo se digitado sem acento.

Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Assim como o usuário pode digitar maiúscula ou minúscula encontra o termo que ele possa digitar com ou sem acento que encontre também.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Função que remove os acentos, se restar alguma dúvida coloque no comentário.

```js
    $(function(){
     $("#txtBusca").keyup(function(){
        var texto = removerAcentos($(this).val());
          $(this).val(texto);
      });
    });




        function removerAcentos( newStringComAcento ) {
          var string = newStringComAcento;
         var mapaAcentosHex  = {
          a : /[\xE0-\xE6]/g,
          e : /[\xE8-\xEB]/g,
          i : /[\xEC-\xEF]/g,
          o : /[\xF2-\xF6]/g,
          u : /[\xF9-\xFC]/g,
          c : /\xE7/g,
          n : /\xF1/g
         };

         for ( var letra in mapaAcentosHex ) {
          var expressaoRegular = mapaAcentosHex[letra];
          string = string.replace( expressaoRegular, letra );
         }

         return string;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtBusca">
```

Comment: Pode explicar como funciona o mapa de acentos?

Comment: a : /[\xE0-\xE6]/g logo os caracteres entre eles serão trocados por 'a', e assim sucessivamente podendo ser modificada facilmente.

Comment: @MateusVeloso Obrigado pela resposta, mas isso só resolve a questão dos acentos e também não sei como fica este código em meu script, desculpe minha ignorância se puder colocar já como devo usar, rsrs é que já passei muitos dias quebrando a cabeça e não consegui fazer funcionar. De qualquer modo obrigado.

Comment: Irie adicionar em seu código

Comment: adicionei na sua script a que eu postei para remover os acentos. perceba que sua variável texto agora recebe já sem o acento.

Comment: @MateusVeloso, cara, fico muito grato!

Comment: @MiguelSilva de nada, funcionou ?

Comment: @MateusVeloso funfou não, agora nem se eu colocar com acentos ele não encontra a palavra, só encontra palavra sem acento, rsrs e também está dando erro ao executar aqui no fórum

Comment: @MiguelSilva verifique agora. e tente adaptar

Comment: @MateusVeloso, agora nem busca ele faz mais, rsrs, se vc copiar html e adicionar o script na própria página pra testar é mais fácil.

Comment: Marque o 'v' para sinalizar que a reposta lhe ajudou, enquanto a reputação não tem problema, estou aqui pra ajudar.

Comment: @MateusVeloso o script ainda não está funcionando.

Comment: Execute o código aqui mesmo no site e tente colocar um 'á' por exemplo

Comment: @MateusVeloso realmente no input ele retira o acento, mas não encontra o texto caso ele tenha acento, não sei se é possível, mas o que quero é que se o usuário digitar um determinado termo que contenha acento, mesmo que ele digite sem acento seja encontrado, entende?