# Como remover todos os caracteres ilegíveis de transformar uma String em um nome de variável para Firebase?

Tags: javascript, regex, firebase, replace

Estou com um problema de cadastro. Eu cadastro em um formulário onde a pessoa coloca o nome do alimento, algo como isso:

```
<div>
  <!-- FOOD -->   
  <div>
      <label for="food">Alimento</label>
      <input autocomplete="off" type="text" id="food" placeholder="Alimento...">
  </div>
</div>
```

E quando o meu formulário é feito o submit, isso acontece em meu script:

```
$('form').submit(async event => {
     event.preventDefault();
     $('#save').prop('disabled', true);

     let food = $('#food').val();
     let id = food.replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/\./g, '').replace(/[\])}[{(]/g, '').toLowerCase() + '&&' + food;

     // Serialize the form and add opening date
     let formData = $('form').serializeJSON();
     formData = Object.assign(formData, {
           "food": id
     });
});
```

Eu crio esse corpo pro meu formulário, colocando o "`food`" com o valor que vem do meu input só que tentei colocar um replace para que não viesse espaços em branco e nem viesse pontos ou parênteses. Alguém consegue me ajudar a incrementar esse replace para que ele renomeie todos as letras que vierem com acento? como por exemplo a palavra "Feijão" ficar como apenas "feijao".

Comment: Além do link já indicado acima no box azul, ver também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124754/112052 | https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/148180/112052

Comment: Vi que vc mudou de "acentos" para "caracteres ilegíveis", mas creio que agora a solução abaixo não sirva mais - por exemplo, ela não remove hífens, que é um dos caracteres citados no título. Na verdade tem vários caracteres que ela não remove, [veja aqui um exemplo](https://ideone.com/0bVca0) - e nesse link também tem uma sugestão de solução (como a definição de "ilegível" ficou meio vaga, eu assumi que é "tudo que não seja letra", mas sugiro editar a pergunta deixando mais claro o que é considerado "ilegível").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicionei o código

```
normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")
```

E deu tudo certo, muito prático e rápido, no fim ficou assim:

```
let id = food.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/\./g, '').replace(/[\])}[{(]/g, '').toLowerCase() + '&&' + food;
```